# cmake find_package: why cannot find some components in boost

Tags: c++, boost

Find_package command is a nightmare to me.
I am trying to include some specified components in boost into my project.
Some components could not be found with find_package command for different error.
Can anyone help to explain the error reported?

case 1:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(tryBoost)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(BOOST_ROOT "D:\\cygwin64\\home\\yubo\\boost_1_62_0") # either set it here or from the command line
find_package(Boost 1.62.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS json) # header only libraries must not be added here
add_executable(tryBoost main.cpp)
```

I try to find *json*, but error reported：
**No header defined for json; skipping header check**

case 2:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(tryBoost)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(BOOST_ROOT "D:\\cygwin64\\home\\yubo\\boost_1_62_0") # either set it here or from the command line
find_package(Boost 1.62.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system) # header only libraries must not be added here
add_executable(tryBoost main.cpp)
```

I try to find *system*, but error reported：
**Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system)**

How boost organizes its components in sub dirs? How find_package command works when scaning boost root dir? why "header only libraries must not be added here".

thanks.

Comment: Make `set( Boost_DEBUG ON)`  which should print out much more info.

Comment: Did you just download/unpack boost? You have to build it.

Comment: @Jellyboy It useful and by debuging I solved the first issue: json.hpp is not included in boost1.62.0. I should have use a later version such as boost1.78.0. ----- I will build it on cygwin later to check the second issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below CMakeList.txt for reference.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(tryBoost)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
#set(Boost_DEBUG ON)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

set(BOOST_ROOT "/home/yubo/boost_1_78_0")

add_executable(tryBoost main.cpp)


set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE FALSE CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
find_package(Boost 1.78.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS json)
message("${Boost_FOUND}")

message("Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
target_include_directories(tryBoost PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

message("Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message("Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
target_link_libraries(tryBoost  ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```